# ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis in count

Tags: sql, oracle

Source data:

```
+------------------------+--------+
|Token                   |Number of stores
+------------------------+--------+
| 1asdfsw2               |     2  |
| 2jkhrwi93              |     1  |
| 3awewqe                |     5   |
+------------------------+--------+
```

The task:
Get the persentage of tokens (credit cards) that appear in transactions in 1 store, in 2 stores (= number of stores) etc.

Num_store could be 1-10 (number of stores where this card was used)
Total_token or 38419611 is the total amount of cards.

I need to get a table like

```
+------------------------+--------+
| Num_stores             |Percentage
+------------------------+--------+
| 1                      |     75 |
| 2                      |      16|
| 3                      |    5   |
+------------------------+--------+
```

When I try

```
select count(ns.num_stores = 1) / tt.total_token * 100
from number_of_stores ns, total_token tt
```

OR

```
select (count(ns.num_stores = 1) / tt.total_token * 100)
from number_of_stores ns, total_token tt
```

OR

```
select count(ns.num_stores = 1) / 38419611 * 100  
from number_of_stores ns
```

OR

```
select (count(ns.num_stores = 1) / 38419611 * 100)   
from number_of_stores ns
```

I got ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis in 1st row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oracle SQL doesn't have a Boolean datatype, unfortunately. If it did, and `count()` was overloaded to treat `true` as `1`, this would be a great use for it.

Comment: This is not the case :) Here num_stores could be 1,2,3 etc, so this is just regular integer, not a check that num_stores exist. But thanks for your comment!

Comment: The expression `ns.num_stores = 1` would evaluate to true or false, if Oracle SQL supported Boolean. As it does not, and `count()` expects a numeric expression, the parser rejects the `=` symbol, hence the error message. It's expecting something like `count(ns.num_stores)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
count(ns.num_stores = 1)
```

It seems you meant to say

```
sum(case when ns.num_stores = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
```

instead.

---

Or, perhaps you should move that "condition" into the `where` clause, e.g.

```
select count(*) / 38419611 * 100  
from number_of_stores ns
where ns.num_stores = 1
```

---

**[EDIT, based on sample data you posted]**

Would something like this help? You'd need lines #12 onward (lines 1 - 11 represent sample data):

```
SQL> with test (token, num_stores) as
  2    (select '39', 4 from dual union all
  3     select '57', 2 from dual union all
  4     select 'fe', 1 from dual union all
  5     select 'e7', 1 from dual union all
  6     select 'bd', 2 from dual union all
  7     select '6d', 3 from dual union all
  8     select 'be', 7 from dual union all
  9     select '6f', 4 from dual union all
 10     select '45', 1 from dual
 11    )
 12  select distinct
 13    num_stores,
 14    round(count(*) over (partition by num_stores) /
 15          count(*) over (partition by null) * 100
 16         ) pct
 17  from test
 18  order by num_stores;

NUM_STORES        PCT
---------- ----------
         1         33
         2         22
         3         11
         4         22
         7         11

SQL>
```

Comment: sum(case when ns.num_stores = 1 then 1 else 0 end) worked well. But what if I need to get differents rows or at least columns where Num_stores = 2, 3, ... and divide sum of these stores to the same / 38419611 * 100 ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you meant to say.

Comment: Maybe I don't need to sum it up? Because the task is to divide count of cases when token is in transactions only in one store and divide it to all number of tokens to get the percentage.

Comment: Could you, please, post sample data and result you'd want to get (do that by editing the question; don't put it into a comment).

Comment: You posted desired result, but - what is the source? I'd need that too.

Comment: Thank you. I posted some more code in my example; have a look, please.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! You are awesome? Could you explain this part (count(\*) over (partition by num_stores) /
 15          count(\*) over (partition by null) * 100? I don't see the division on total number of tokens.

Comment: You're welcome. I used analytic COUNT functions; the first one counts rows ("tokens") partitioned by NUM_STORES, while the second one doesn't use PARTITION BY clause which means that it counts total number of rows so - when you divide those numbers, you get the percentage.

Comment: Probably you could use `ratio_to_report`, though I didn't understand the question enough to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM` with `CASE..WHEN` clause for the same as the following:

> ```
> select sum(case when ns.num_stores = 1 then 1 end) / tt.total_token * 100
> from number_of_stores ns, total_token tt;
> ```

But, this will not work as `tt.total_token` is used as it is so it must be in the `GROUP BY` clause also, I think you should try to sum up them also.

> ```
> select sum(case when ns.num_stores = 1 then 1 end) / sum(tt.total_token) * 100
> from number_of_stores ns, total_token tt;
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Can you please share the sql that you are executing?

Comment: Oracle 9 or 10, I don't know where to find the precise information

Comment: I am talking about the sql query that you are executing

Comment: I tried the queries described in my question and both yours. Sorry, don't get the question

Answer (score 0):

As far as what I understood from your requirement. I think you are trying to group results by num_stores counts. Something like this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(1) / 38419611 * 100  ) , NS.NUM_STORES
FROM NUMBER_OF_STORES NS GROUP BY NS.NUM_STORES
```